# isEqualToSet not returning correct value

Tags: ios, ios7, nsmutableset

I am having two `NSArray` which contains integer values. I want to get common values from both arrays and for this am using `NSMutableSet`.

Here is my code

`

```
    NSMutableSet *set1 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:array1]];

    NSMutableSet *set2 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:array2];

    if (![set1 isEqualToSet:set2])
    {
        [set2 intersectSet:set1];
        NSArray  *commonArray = [set2  allObjects];
     }
```

`

Here is the values in array
`
   array1
   (
    2,
    3
   )

array2 
   (
     2,
     3
   )

`and values in`NSMutableSet` are

`
  set1
  {(
    2,
    3
  )}

set2
  {(
    2,
    3
  )}
`

As per the condition and values the code will not execute the lines inside the `if()` condition. But here the `if()` condition returns wrong value.

Also the `[set2 intersectSet:set1];` returns `set2` as empty.

Anything wrong with this code.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: The code in your If statement is never executed as Set 1 and Set 2 are equal. Also intersectSet removes from the receiving set each object that isn’t a member of another given set. Also you need to use NSNumber with NSSet.

Comment: I just checked it and if set2 is the same as set1 - nothing will be remove.

Comment: @Woodstock Ohh.. I didn't get exactly why it is not executed. can you please explain little bit more as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things here, one you need to use `NSNumber` with `NSMutableSet`, you can't just use standard `int`.

NSNumber is effectively an int wrapped in a Class, NSSet requires NSNumber as it deals with **objects**.

The code in your if statement will only be executed if (as per your logic above) the two sets are not equal. (! isEqualToSet).

However isEqualToSet only returns YES if the contents of otherSet are equal to the contents of the receiving set, otherwise NO.

Finally `intersectSet` **removes from the receiving set each object that isn’t a member of another given set. - yielding the intersection.**

This is important to understand. You want to get common values from the two sets. Whereas Intersect will simply **remove** the values from one set **not** found in the other.

Therefore `[set2 intersectSet:set1];` checks what values which are in Set 2 also exist in Set 1.

Thus after calling `[set2 intersectSet:set1];` Set 2 will contain any values that are common between both sets.

Make sure you are using NSNumber.

Comment: Thanks for the info. it worked. now what about the second issue. ` interSect ` returns empty Set.